# How to listen close event using ZeroMQ?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

A client script :

```
var ZMQ = require('zeromq')
  , sock = ZMQ.socket('pull');

socket.on('close',function())
{
// print socket closed
   process.exit(1)
}
```

I can't find any proper document for listen a close event.

I want to listen close event so that whenever my server restart I have information of socket closed and I can act accordingly.

Is there any thing to do on server script ?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/blob/master/test/unit/compat/socket-monitor-test.js, around about line 36

Comment: Excellent, @bazza, as always.

Answer (score -1):

> **Q :**
> *" <sub>How to listen close event using ZeroMQ?</sub> "*

**A :**
Either of
 a) using native-API documented `socket_monitor`
 b) using the current `node.js` language binding re-wrapped `socket_monitor`, if present
c) creating an extension to the current binding, in case b) turns out not having included the `socket_monitor` yet
d) not using low-level tooling, yet creating one's own Signalling/Messaging meta-plane, that keeps heartbeating & similar self-detecting / self-healing telemetry flow, upon which data-content or an absence in due time thereof, your code can start reactive actions if SIG/MSG meta-plane state reconfiguration is self-detected.

Comment: can you give any code example or any documentation that implement close event ...that would be very helpful..thanks

Comment: As @bazza commented above, the node.js (as-is) binding completely ignores this even (does NOP on receiving it even inside monitor-handler ) -- https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/blob/0651e4546952c4ee7056d38b6e1a833b81157832/src/compat.ts#L521 For a documented native-API see http://wiki.zeromq.org/docs:core-api + http://api.zeromq.org/4-3:zmq-socket-monitor + Did you try to type in a Google search before asking others to give you code? This is considered unfair on this Site, so a friendly advice - better re-read again the Community Rules about what is within the Community Netiquette & what not